# Shabbos Breishis

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, shabbat

Why is only Shabbos Breishis known as Shabbos Breishis. (As opposed to any other week - we do not call Shabbos Noach etc.)

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5204.

Comment: Sourcing these assertions would improve this question.

Answer (score 5):

Someone showed me a Divrei Chaim that asks this question and answers as follows. During the month of Tishrei people take upon themselves to better themselves. To remind people that they are starting with a clean slate we call this Shabbos "Shabbos Breishis". Just like by Breishis everything started anew, the same is now with us.

Comment: That's a nice thought!

Comment: It's also the best time to start the habit of being maavir sedrah.

Comment: @yydl a rav once told me that on Simchat Torah & Shavuot he is extra inspired to review the parsha.  But Bereishit can be a short week (until Simchat Torah, the parsha is v'zot habracha), so it can be very challenging.  The parsha after Shavuot is often (not always) Naso, which is very long.  So it is challenging to study the parsha at these times.