# What is the origin of the naming of Shabbat Shira?

Tags: sources-mekorot, shabbat, names, provenance, beshalach

Related to [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5204/why-is-parshas-beshalach-called-shabbos-shira) question (about the reason for the name), what is the *source or origin* of calling the Shabbat on which we read Shirat Hayam [Shabbat Shira](https://books.google.com/books?id=KJ5q6gsLSu0C&pg=PA185&lpg=PA185&dq=%22shabbat%20shirah%22%20origin&source=bl&ots=uTdYcrKVPP&sig=Dh6oOusb7jn53TXE9MmCi0tL99Y&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjBgoi0uIfZAhVHuVMKHRWmB-AQ6AEIjgEwEg#v=onepage&q=%22shabbat%20shirah%22%20origin&f=false)?

We don't call the week on which we read the Shirat [Hab'er](http://www.angelfire.com/pa2/passover/10-shirot.html) a Shabbat Shira though its content is no less a Shir and the events of Matan Torah are no less unifying or miraculous but we have nothing called "Shabbat Matan Torah" or an equivalent.

What was the process by which this particular Shabbat became known by a specific name whereas others were not labelled?

Comment: Could it be that it's called Shabbos Shirah because both the Torah and Haftorah portions contain a song?

Comment: Besides being the first song denoted in the Torah, I also note that unlike the song of the well, and *Ha'azinu*, this song was song by both Moshe and B'nai Yisra'el. It seems to have, therefore, more significance than *Shirat Hab'er*.

Comment: I have found that the Named Shabatot have their names from the Haftarah - No  credible and/or official source.

Comment: @DannySchoemann, what about ד׳ פרשיות ? They're usually named for their contents or a quote from their krioh

Answer (score 1):

Shabat Shira called so because we read Shirat Hayam and in the Haftorah we read Shirat Devora.

Similarly, Shabat Hazon, Shabat Shuva, and Shabat Nahamu are named after their Haftorah.