# Would someone please characterize Shabbat Shirah

Tags: halacha, shabbat, history

I am fairly unfamiliar with Judaism and I happened upon a special Sabbath that I had not seen before. It occurs in late January or early February and is known as Shabbat Shirah. I would appreciate it if someone could provide some history, significance, and insights. Would Shabbat Shirah be considered a blessed day?

Perhaps the following will add more clarity to my question.

"Why is this day set apart as a special sabbath?" and "Is this special sabbath (in particular) characterized by "joy, happiness, or gladness" as might be suggested by a (celebrant) "song" of deliverance?"

Comment: Relevant: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5204/why-is-parshas-beshalach-called-shabbos-shira

Comment: I am most interested in the "song" and it's general mood and significance to the word "blessed" - less in the tradition of bird feeding...

Comment: I'm not sure how you are defining a "blessed day". It's not a concept I'm familiar with in Judaism

Comment: @JoelK - Yes, there are many facets to the word "blessed". Does this help in any way? Meanings 1 and 3 are most relevant in my thinking - https://www.thefreedictionary.com/blessed

Comment: Every shabbat is holy (e.g. Genesis 2:3) and brings pleasure (e.g Isaiah 58:13). I'm not aware of shabbat shirah being different in these regards

Comment: @JoelK - Allow me to rephrase the question(s) then (for you). Please don't think too hard about my question. -- for clarification -- "Why is this day set apart as a special sabbath?" and "Is this special sabbath (in particular) characterized by "joy, happiness, or gladness" as might be suggested by a (celebrant) "song" of deliverance?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shabbat Shirah occurs in the annual cycle of reading the Torah when we reach the parasha of [Beshalach](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beshalach). That section of the Torah contains the [Song of the Sea](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Song_of_the_Sea). Consequently, that shabbat is called "Shabbat Shirah," meaning "Sabbath of Song."

This section of the Torah is read with a special tune in many communities and some communities have instituted minor traditions marking the celebratory nature of the day in commemoration of escaping from Egypt. But by and large Shabbat Shirah is not observed differently from a normal Sabbath.